# Pass Javascript value as part of php url parameter

Tags: javascript, html, magento2

I want to pass a JavaScript variable as comment parameter in disableReason function in redirectLocation as part of URL.
I have got text area value from

```
var disableComment = document.getElementsByClassName("disable-comment")[0].value;
```

I am not able pass the javascript var into the url as parameter .

```
$html .= '<button type="button" class="scalable back" onclick="showDiv()">' . __($sellerText) . '</button>';
$html .= '<script>function showDiv() {document.getElementById("disable-reason").style.display = "block";}</script>';    
$html .= '<div style="display:none" id="disable-reason"><label for="disable-reason">Disable Reason</label><textarea class="disable-comment" name="disable-comment" rows="2" cols="25"></textarea><button type="button" class="scalable back" onclick="disableReason()">' . __($sellerText) . '</button><script>function disableReason() {var disableComment = document.getElementsByClassName("disable-comment")[0].value;redirectLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('mpadmin/marketplace/sellerAccountEnable', ['id' => $data['entity_id'],'status'=>$sellerStatusData,'comment'=>'**variable here** ']) . '\');}</script></div>';
```

Can you please help .

Comment: You show PHP which is server side. You would need to pass the comment to the server using AJAX

Comment: @mplungjan any example ?

Answer (score 0):

we can access Php variable using JavaScript. but we can't directly access JavaScript variable value using Php because php, python, java that are Server Side Languages. and JavaScript, jQuery is a Client Side Languages...

for Pass Value of Javascript Variable to Server Side languages you need to Call **AJAX Request**

```
$.ajax({
   url: example.com/test.php, //pass here Url...
        type: 'GET', //method type ... GET, POST
        dataType: 'html', //(html or JSON) not necessary but if you want to need pass then you can..
        headers: {
            // if you need pass authentication tokens then you can do it using headers in AJAX request
        },
        data: { 
            id: id; // pass here your data which you want to pass
        },
        success: function (data) {
            here you will be get success Response
        }
    });
```